# Why find_if not working in my program?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have a simple program that calls `std::find_if`, I think I've pass the first two argument as iterator and the third as a predict, however the code still won't compile, any ideas?

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

bool notspace(char ch);
bool space(char ch);

int main()  {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
    iter i;
    std::string s = "ab c";
    i = std::find_if(i, s.end(),space);
    return 0;
}

bool space(char ch)  {
    return std::isspace(ch);
}
```

Error message:

```
q-isspace.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
q-isspace.cpp:12:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(iter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))’
     i = std::find_if(i, s.end(),space);
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
                 from q-isspace.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Predicate> _IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate)
     find_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3806:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
q-isspace.cpp:12:38: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
     i = std::find_if(i, s.end(),space);
```

Comment: `i` and `j` are not initialized to anything. So where is `find_if` supposed to start from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You pass `i` which is of type `std::string::const_iterator`(and also uninitialized) as first parameter to `std::find_if`. Then you pass `s.end()` which returns a `std::string::iterator`. The two iterators are of different types, while `std::find_if` expects them to be of the same type.

The correct rule of thumb, is to pair the calls to `begin()` and `end()`

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

bool notspace(char ch);
bool space(char ch);

int main()  {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
    iter i,j;
    std::string s = "ab c";
    i = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),notspace);
    j = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),space);
    return 0;
}

bool space(char ch)  {
    return std::isspace(ch);
}

bool notspace(char ch)   {
    return !std::isspace(ch);
}
```

Comment: Will that matter if one is `const_iterator` and the other is `iterator`?

Comment: @buzhidao, yes. Template function type deduction is very specific. `std::find_if` names only one `InputIterator` type

Comment: I found that when I used a `const` before the `std::string`, there will also be no compiling errors.

Comment: @buzhidao, it becomes evident why, when you consider the overloads of [`std::string::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end). Note the return type of `std::string::end() const;`

Answer (score 6):

```
int main()  {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
    iter i,j;
    std::string s = "ab c";
    i = std::find_if(i, s.end(),notspace);
    j = std::find_if(i, s.end(),space);
    return 0;
}
```

You're not initalising your `i` variable, so it is not pointing to anything. This means that `[i, s.end())` does not form a valid range, so your call to `find_if()` will not work correctly.

Try this instead:

```
i = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), notspace);
```

Comment: @juanchopanza `const_iterator` for `i`, `iterator` for `s.end()`, deduction failure?

Answer (score 3):

```
iter i,j;
std::string s = "ab c";
i = std::find_if(i, s.end(),notspace);
```

This calls `std::find_if` with a default-initialized iterator as its first argument. That iterator has no relation to any iterator into `s`, so the result will be nonsense. Change the call to

```
`std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), notspace);
```

And make the analogous change in the other call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler error is due to the iterators having different type.

Comment: @juanchopanza - yup, probably also needs to change the typedef to `typedef std::string::iterator iter;` so that the return type matches.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know why your compilation errors, it's because `std::find_if` only has 1 template parameter. `s.end()` is a normal iterator while `i` is a `const_iterator`, those don't match up. And then there's the problem with `i` being uninitialized which will cause you a runtime error. Just use `s.begin()`:

```
i = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),space);
```

If you want to be able to change contents through `i`, you should make it a normal iterator:

```
typedef std::string::iterator iter;
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` variable is not initialized. The more elegent way to code is to use lambda function as given below.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <algorithm>

    int main()  {
        typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
        iter i,j;
        std::string s = "ab c";
        i = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),[](char ch) { return std::isspace(ch); } );
        j = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),[](char ch) { return !std::isspace(ch); } );
        return 0;
     }
```